# JQuery ajax post back id with checkbox object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a table with of clients with multiple checkboxes:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Clients)
    {          
        <tr class="@highlightRowClass" data-clientnumber="@item.ClientNumber">  
            <td>
                @Html.CheckboxFor(modelItem => item.Checkbox1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.CheckBox2)
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
```

I want to have an ajax call the posts back the array of ids with an object that represents if one or both of the checkboxes are ticked:

```
             var obj = {
                CheckBox1Ticked: true, 
                Checkbox2Ticked: false,
            };
            pendingChanges[clientId] = obj ;
```

How would I loop through each table row and populate the array using Jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the array like this:

```
var checkboxData = $('table tr').map(function() {
    var $inputs = $(this).find('input');
    return { checkbox1Ticked: $inputs.eq(0).prop('checked'), checkbox2Ticked: $inputs.eq(1).prop('checked') };
});
```

`checkboxData` is then an array you can pass/interrogate as required:

```
console.log(checkboxData[0].checkbox1Ticked);
```

Comment: Thanks, modified it slightly to include the clientId and fixed minor syntax error (also bear in mind that the header row will need to be ignored):   `var checkboxData = $('table tr').map(function() {        
    var $inputs = $(this).find('input');
    return { clientId : $(this).data("clientnumber") , checkbox1Ticked : $inputs.eq(0).prop('checked'), checkbox2Ticked : $inputs.eq(1).prop('checked') };
});`